# ERROR - Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When I try to understand a spring boot project I pulled a code in GITHUB.
In spring boot project, I had set all my datasource connections in application.properties file.  But it is throwing Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE error.Please help me to get through this error.

ERROR

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
>   2018-11-06 16:50:14.824 ERROR 64016 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :
>
> ---
>
> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE
>
> Action:
>
> If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).

Below is my application.properties

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/CSI
spring.datasource.username = s******r
spring.datasource.password = T*****d
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Pom. xml

```
<groupId>com.social</groupId>
<artifactId>springBoot-angular4-auth</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>springBoot-angular4-authentication</name>
<description>authentication api</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.9</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>

        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.11</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: try to add `spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect` and change `driverClassName`to `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`.

Comment: for ref: https://github.com/dineshbhagat/spring-boot-web-jpa

Comment: Oh. @Alien it was faster :/

Comment: yes @CristianoBombazar it was easily visible after error log...:P

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [documentation1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/connector-j-8.0-en/connector-j-api-changes.html) and [documentation2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-api-changes.html)

**changes to the Connector/J API going from version 5.1 to 8.0**

*The name of the class that implements java.sql.Driver in MySQL Connector/J has changed from com.mysql.jdbc.Driver to com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver. The old class name has been deprecated.*

Check the mysql connector version maven dependency jars if it is 8 then `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` should have worked.

But still try changing `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` to `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

and add

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Refer [application.properties](https://github.com/springframeworkguru/spring-boot-mysql-example/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.properties)